# Does China have any website like Youtube?

Tags: learning

I want to let learn about Chinese and I want to watch some short video to begin with. Is there any website like Youtube in China and can be access from USA?

Comment: Youku, Tudou, iQiyi

Comment: supplement @StumpyJoePete's comment.
The most of TV programs and dramas don't have copyright to broadcast overseas. Bilibili is better.

Comment: @马化腾, Another good one is **Tencent Video**. Is that yours? lol

Comment: @dan, ………………

Answer (score 3):

We have [bilibili](https://www.bilibili.com/) and [acfun](http://www.acfun.cn/) .

Comment: acfun is mostly dead now :P

Comment: @Kevin.Fang no idea..cuz I don't really use them. 

Answer (score 0):

There is baidu or sougou in China but I didn't surf the internet that much while I was in China so I wouldn't know which site is better.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access [youku](http://youku.com) and [tudou](http://tudou.com) from Germany a few years ago, so you might want to try those.

On a slightly different note, what sort of content are you looking for?