# Does Taiwan have any website like YouTube?

Tags: learning

([Inspired](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/31422/19184)) I want to let learn about Chinese and I want to watch some short video to begin with. Is there any website like Youtube in Taiwan and can be access from USA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am Taiwanese and think there isn't. You can try the different keywords in YouTube like:
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=taiwan

Comment: I forgot to say that Taiwanese love using YouTube. :P